# How to validate that a number cannot be entered in a text input in FormKit

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, formkit

I am using FormKit in a Nuxt 3 + Vue 3 project. I wanted to add a validation check on an input textbox to ensure that if a user enters only numbers, then the user is informed that the input is invalid and must enter some text.

For example:

12345 --> INVALID input

Engineer 1 --> This is fine

The formkit documentation has this as an example: See, https://formkit.com/essentials/validation#number

```
<FormKit
  type="text"
  label="Age"
  validation="number"
  value="27365 days old"
  validation-visibility="live"
/>
```

The above code ensures that a user must enter only numbers. How do I reverse this ensuring that the user cannot enter only numbers? I have tried the below but none seem to be working:

Option 1: `!number` does not work

```
<FormKit
  type="text"
  label="Position"
  validation="!number"
/>
```

Option 1: `not:number` does not work (I know it cannot be used this way. Just tried it out)

```
<FormKit
  type="text"
  label="Position"
  validation="not:number"
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fenilli is correct that you'll want to register a custom rule for this type of thing if you need to use it across your project.

You can also achieve this inline using the array syntax for validation rules and a function that's in scope of your component in the event you only need it as a one-off.

```js
<script setup>
const cannotBeOnlyNumbers = ({ value }) => {
  const regex = /^(?![0-9]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{2,}$/
  return regex.test(String(value))
}
</script>

<template>
  <FormKit
    type="text"
    :validation="[['required'],[cannotBeOnlyNumbers]]"
    :validation-messages="{
      cannotBeOnlyNumbers: 'Value cannot be only numbers.',
    }"
    validation-visibility="live"
    label="FormKit Input"
    help="edit me to get started"
  />
</template>
```

Live playground example can be seen here: https://formkit.link/b146d29c77521f621fe04e2f3e976957

for documentation on adding a validation rule globally see: https://formkit.com/essentials/validation#adding-a-rule-globally

Comment: How do I add the rule to the `formkit.config.ts` file so that I can use the validation globally? I saw the link to the documentation you gave, but not sure of how to add it. Currently, my `formkit.config.ts` has this ```import { DefaultConfigOptions } from "@formkit/vue";

const config: DefaultConfigOptions = {
  theme: "genesis",
};

export default config;
```

Comment: As I am using typescript, what type is the `value`?

Comment: Boyd answer is better as it only allows numbers and strings instead of strings or numbers or both.

As for the type from `value` it is `unknow`.

Comment: As to how to add that globally you can add it to your `{ theme: 'genesis', rules: { cannotBeOnlyNumbers } }`

Comment: @GustavoFenilli `unknown` does not seem to be working. But I added `any` which resolved the typescript error. `const cannotBeOnlyNumbers = ({ value }: any) => {}`. Is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

Happy to see you're using FormKit!

As per documentation https://formkit.com/essentials/validation#rule-hints there isn't a rule-hint for `!` and the rule `not` doesn't accept other rules as its input, so for your case the best would be to create a custom rule like `alphanumeric_spaces` like so:

```js
const alphanumeric_spaces: FormKitValidationRule = function (
  { value },
  set = 'default'
) {
  const sets = {
    default: /^[\p{Lu}\p{L} ]+$/u,
    latin: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/,
  }
  const selectedSet: 'default' | 'latin' = has(sets, set) ? set : 'default'
  return sets[selectedSet].test(String(value))
}
```

Comment: This is giving me a lot of typescript errors for value, selectedSet, and has. Trying to fix these...